# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object

Tags: php, kohana, simpletest, phactory

This code get an error: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\kohana\application\controllers\phactory2_test.php on line 16
It's the example from the Phactory guide: http://phactory.org/guide/#phpunit-example

```
<?php
include_once('/simpletest/autorun.php');
require_once ('/Phactory/lib/Phactory.php');

/**
  * This is the function we will test.
  * It should retrieve a user from the db by id,
  * and return that user's age.
  *
  * @param PDO $pdo
  * @param int $user_id
  * @return mixed The age of the user, or false if no user
  */
function getUserAge($pdo, $user_id)
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
    $user = $stmt->fetch();

    if(false === $user) {
        return false;
    }

    return $user['age'];
}

class UserTest extends UnitTestCase
{   
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        // create a db connection and tell Phactory to use it
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=testdb', 'root', '');
        Phactory::setConnection($pdo);

        /**
          * Normally you would not need to create a table here, and would use
          * an existing table in your test database instead.
          * For the sake of creating a self-contained example, we create
          * the 'users' table here.
          */
        $pdo->exec("CREATE TABLE `users` ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, age INTEGER )");

        // reset any existing blueprints and empty any tables Phactory has used
        Phactory::reset();

        // define default values for each user we will create
        Phactory::define('user', array('name' => 'Test User $n', 'age' => 18));
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {
        Phactory::reset();

        // since we created a table in this test, we must drop it as well
        Phactory::getConnection()->exec("DROP TABLE `users`");
    }

    public function testGetUserAge()
    {
        // test that getUserAge() returns false for a nonexistent user
        $age = getUserAge(Phactory::getConnection(), 0);
        $this->assertFalse($age);

        // create 20 users, with ages from 1-20
        $users = array();
        for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) 
        {
            // create a row in the db with age = $i, and store a Phactory_Row object
            $users[] = Phactory::create('user', array('age' => $i));
        }

        // test that getUserAge() returns the correct age for each user
        foreach($users as $user) 
        {
            // Phactory_Row provides getId() which returns the value of the PK column
            $user_id = $user->getId();

            $age = getUserAge(Phactory::getConnection(), $user_id);

            $this->assertEqual($user->age, $age);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

What is the possible cause?
Thank you

Edit: I found out the problem, Phactory::getConnection() is returning NULL for some reason

Comment: Enclose all of your interactions with the database with try catch blocks. Doing this will ensure you can exit the script inside the catch if needed but also also gives you a way to catch the errors and either rethrow them or print them out.

try {

    // Database connection or queries here

} catch (PDOException $e) {


    echo $e->getMessage();

}

Answer (score 1):

You must add bind_param before execute prepared statement.

```
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);
    $stmt->execute();
```

This is on MySQL connection. For pdo you can add

```
print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
```

To find out what is your problem.

Comment: `$stmt->execute(array($user_id));` <- I think you overlook this line